# Shortening the height of a data grid to fit rows of variable height

Tags: datagrid

#### Context for this question

We have a web page that has two scrolling grids, not paginated grids. When the first grid is nearly empty, occasional users do not realize they can scroll down to see the second grid. Other layouts (tabs, etc. are not a desirable solution).

> **Aside**. The entire page layout is due for an overhaul, but on the Development schedule it's still 2 years away. Today, we cannot remove the grids, and we cannot change the general layout of this page.

When the first grid contains very little content, it would be good to auto-shorten the first grid so that the second grid peeks up above the fold. But when the first grid has lots of content, it's better if the first grid remains at its default height, because this grid is where the main interaction takes place, and we don't want excessive scrolling.

The challenge is that, in the grids, *each row varies in height* to fit its content. Sometimes a row is 2 lines of text, sometimes 12 lines of text. This causes a hard-coded height based on the number or rows inappropriate.

[image: Illustration showing the two grids on the page]

#### The question

What methods are there to assess the height of the row content in the first grid so that, if the total is less than the default grid height, we can shorten the grid? Or is there another way to look at this problem?

Comment: Can we see the code that you have attempted?

Comment: I feel silly saying this, but—unfortunately—no. There's a copyright dispute between two corporate partners. I can make suggestions but I cannot see the code. :p